# How can I use OverrideAuthorization globally to authorize a specific role in MVC (without forcing authorization over the entire program)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a web application where I want to implement authorization at the controller level using roles. I plan on having multiple controllers, with most controllers utilizing a specific role for authorization. My issue, though, is that I also want to have a role that can be used globally across all controllers and actions. How exactly can I do this?

I've seen a TON of articles on locking things down the opposite way. For example, I know you can go to the FilterConfig.cs file and add a line like this:

```
filter.add(new AuthorizeAttribute() {Roles = "Administrator" });
```

But I don't want to approach it this way! This makes it so that every action must have the Administrator role. On top of that, if I use this the only way to get what I want in the controller is then to do:

```
[OverrideAuthorization]
[Authorize(Roles = "MyControllerRole")]
```

Some controllers I don't want to use any authorization on, and others I only need to use authorization on a few actions. If I use the above global authorization, I'd have to put this override on every single controller!

Is there some kind of special global override authorization where I can tell my program: "*regardless of what roles are used for this controller or action, if the user has the 'Administrator' role they can access this action*"?

Comment: you say  "if the user has the 'Administrator' role they can access this action", implies you do want this specific role to have access..but the question is access to what? MVC is not your app. its a design approach. users dont access your MVC. they access your controllers. you have 1 or 2 or x controllers, and you already said, you have a role that MUST access all controllers, so you specify the role at the controller. alternatively, you can set a default role at the time of account setup, so everybody has access to all controllers with the default Authorize attribute.

Comment: further 'I'd have to put this override on every single controller'. how would this affect your software design? are your changing controllers and user roles every day, that they are constantly being shuffled around? i am just curious to understand the context of this problem.if there is a role that needs access all controllers, how hard is to simply add that role when you add a new controller to your project.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Regarding your first comment: I want this specific role to have access to ALL actions in every controller across my application, regardless of how the controller or action is setup for authorization. I didn't mean to imply that I was trying to get MVC to do something (I'll edit my post), but rather that I wanted to implement something THROUGH the MVC design approach. I'm using Windows Authentication, so setting a default role at account setup would not be an option. At least, now the way I am trying to get my application to work.

Comment: I'm not changing controllers and user roles every day. Yes, I could add a role at the action level or controller level and simply include "Administrator". However, I feel like this would not make my code dry. That is, I'd rather have this role configured for all controllers/actions in one place rather than every single controller or action. Aside from it being redundant, if another programmer set up a new controller and forgot to add the authorization for the admin role, this could lead to potential problems (though it is easy to remedy, of course).

Comment: To speak on my design logic, I'd essentially have my users in different roles. Alice would manage the HR controller, Bob would manage the Retirement controller, and George would have control over the Press controller. Jake is just a regular user (with no roles), so he can visit some of the actions from each of these controllers, but can't really do any kind of management with the data in these sections. Becky, however, is an administrator. She needs to be able do anything she wants in the HR, Retirement, and Press controllers. Hopefully this clarifies things!

Comment: ah, thank you for the additional clarification. I (think) i have a better idea of what you are doing. ultimately, all I can say, i would just put the extra effort and add roles as required at the top of the controller even if takes a few more minutes to code but gets the job done. the scenario you have now clarified and the plan you want to do, is completely going over my head :) but of course, someone else find help you out here.